# Glob that doesn't match anything expands to itself, rather than to nothing

Tags: linux, bash, glob

I want to iterate over the files in a folder of a special type (like `.test`):

So I wrote a little script names `for_loop`:

```
for f in *.test
do
 echo 'This is f: '${f}
done
```

After (`chmod +x for_loop`) I can start it with `./for_loop`.

If there are `.test`-files, everthing is fine, BUT if there is no file in the folder that matches `*.test`, the for-loop is still executed once. In this case the output looks like:

```
This is f: *.test
```

But I thought that if there were no files in the folder that match the glob pattern, there would be no output. Why is this not the case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the default behaviour.

to get rid of it, enable `nullglob`:

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

From [Greg's Wiki - nullglob](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#nullglob):

> nullglob expands non-matching globs to zero arguments, rather than to
>   themselves.

...

> Without nullglob, the glob would expand to a literal * in an empty
>   directory, resulting in an erroneous count of 1.

Or use `zsh`, which has this glob enabled by default!

```
$ for f in *.test; do echo "$f"; done
zsh: no matches found: *.test
```

Comment: Would you suggest he put that in his script or part of his bashrc or where would you normally put this?

Comment: @ojblass I think it is best to just put it in the script where you want this behaviour. This way, the default behaviour will be present whenever the script stops running. But, of course, if you prefer this behaviour over the default one, you can add it into `~/.bashrc`. In my case, I just use it whenever needed, not as default.