# Array of all files in a directory, except one

Tags: arrays, bash

Trying to figure out how to include all `.txt` files except one called `manifest.txt`.

```
FILES=(path/to/*.txt)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [extended glob patterns](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching) for this:

```
shopt -s extglob
files=(path/to/!(manifest).txt)
```

The `!(pattern-list)` pattern matches "anything except one of the given patterns".

Note that this exactly excludes `manifest.txt` and nothing else; `mmanifest.txt`, for example, would still go in to the array.

---

<sup>As a side note: a glob that matches nothing at all expands to itself (see [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33898250/glob-that-doesnt-match-anything-expands-to-itself-rather-than-to-nothing)). This behaviour can be changed using the `nullglob` (expand to empty string) and `failglob` (print error message) shell options.</sup>

Comment: It does not work for me in a little test I did.  I get an array that contains `!(manifest).txt`  I think you need `nullglob` in addition to `extglob`

Comment: @Fred Looks more like you don't have `extglob` turned on? Notice that it can be turned on in an interactive shell, but turned off in a non-interactive shell, in case you tried this in a script. `nullglob` is not needed, I'd say.

Comment: @BenjaminW.  I can confirm I have reproduced it in an interactive shell.  Simply by disabling `nullglob` (nothing else changed), I go from intended result to the result described in my comment.

Comment: @Fred for a scenario where you don't have any `.txt` files at all? That's the only way I can get what you describe.

Comment: @BenjaminW.  Yes, no `.txt` file ; maybe this case should be handled explicitely?

Comment: @Fred I'll add a note, but it's not really specific to this solution. Any glob based solution would have to take it into account, and I don't think I want to add a list of all possible caveats to all my answers here.

Answer (score 2):

You can build the array one file at a time, avoiding the file you do not want :

```
declare -a files=()
for file in /path/to/files/*
do
  ! [[ -e "$file" ]] || [[ "$file" = */manifest.txt ]] || files+=("$file")
done
```

Please note that globbing in the `for` statement does not cause problems with whitespace (even newlines) in filenames.

**EDIT**

I added a test for file existence to handle the case where the glob fails and the `nullglob` option is not set.

Answer (score 1):

```
FILES=($(ls /path/to/*.txt | grep -wv '^manifest.txt$'))
```

Comment: This still doesn't work if you have files with whitespace and/or wildcards in filenames (which is perfectly legal). Try `touch 'this * is * a * file.txt' manifest.txt`, then use this, then see what the `FILE` array contains.

Comment: @GordonDavisson, it works, even if I create this file with your `touch` command. Please either correct your example or explain.

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz Running my `touch` command in an empty directory, then your command (on `$PWD/*.txt`), then `printf "'%s' " "${FILES[@]}"` gives me `'/Users/gordon/tmp/manifest.txt' '/Users/gordon/tmp/this' 'manifest.txt' 'this * is * a * file.txt' 'is' 'manifest.txt' 'this * is * a * file.txt' 'a' 'manifest.txt' 'this * is * a * file.txt' 'file.txt' `.

Comment: This still expands wildcards. You'd have to quote `$()` to prevent this, but then you'd end up with an array with just one element.

Comment: Works well imho. Do not see any counterexamples.

Comment: Try `touch 'has space.txt'` (as the only file), then your command, then `declare -p FILES` – you'll see that your array has _two_ elements.

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz Did you test my example? The latest update still fails (although slightly less badly). Also, read the BashFAQ item on [why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Answer (score 1):

I think this is best handled with an associative array even if just one element.

Consider:

```
$ touch f{1..6}.txt manifest.txt
$ ls *.txt
f1.txt      f3.txt      f5.txt      manifest.txt
f2.txt      f4.txt      f6.txt
```

You can create an associative array for the names you wish to exclude:

```
declare -A exclude 
for f in f1.txt f5.txt manifest.txt; do 
    exclude[$f]=1
done
```

Then add files to an array that are not in the associative array:

```
files=()
for fn in *.txt; do
    [[ ${exclude[$fn]} ]] && continue
    files+=("$fn")  
done

$ echo "${files[@]}"
f2.txt f3.txt f4.txt f6.txt
```

This approach allows any number of exclusions from the list of files.